# What strings are accepted by the pattern "^[ab]?|c?$"?

Tags: pattern-matching, dfa

What I have gathered till now:

1. ^ -> match the first symbol
2. $ -> match the last symbol
3. [] -> set of characters that can be in the position
4. | -> the "OR" operator
5. ? -> the previous condition is optional

---

What I think the pattern means:
The line has to either begin with an `a` or a `b` or has to end with a `c` or has to be an empty string. I am having trouble drawing the dfa for the pattern though. What's throwing me off is the "optional" symbol. I am not able to understand what strings won't be accepted in the language.

---

Can someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Have you tried _testing_ this regexp against various input text?

Comment: You mean like using the Java Pattern Matcher or something?

Comment: I mean using any tool or language that can do regular expressions.  There are many to choose from.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Reference - What does this regex mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22937618/reference-what-does-this-regex-mean)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`^` matches the start of the line.

`[ab]?` matches "a", or "b", or nothing.

`c?` matches "c", or nothing.

`$` matches the end of the line.

So, I think these lines will match:

```
(empty line)
a
b
c
```

Comment: Ok, but then what's the difference between the Pattern in question and something like `^[ab]|c$`?

Comment: Is the question mark on both of those just to incorporate an empty string?

Comment: The difference is that nothing is optional in that pattern, so an empty line would not match.

Comment: The question mark does exactly what you said -- it makes the previous pattern optional, meaning the pattern can occur one or zero times.

Comment: Ah! So the Pattern in question is basically the equivalent of `^[ab]|c$|^$` (assuming `^$` is how one represents the empty string).

Comment: No, it is not equivalent.  The first pattern in your comment matches "a" or "b" at the beginning of a line **and does not specify what comes next**, and the second pattern matches "c" at the end of a line **and does not specify what came before that**.